# The meaning of "a region of data space where the model is poorly constrained"

Tags: neural-networks, bayesian, uncertainty, adversarial-example

In reading *"Understanding Measures of Uncertainty for Adversarial Example Detection"* (Gal, Lewis) - https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.08533, I came across the following line:

> "we want to capture when an input lies in a region of data space where the model is poorly constrained" (pg. 4).

Can someone explain to me what it means for a model to be "poorly constrained" in this context?

Comment: In regions of input data space where there are not too many training examples the model output has high variance and is somewhat arbitrary...

Comment: Thanks for the answer! To follow up: what does it means for a model to be "poorly constrained" then? If you're saying it means when the model output has high variance and is somewhat arbitrary, how does that distinguish from when the model is given inputs that are near the data distribution but have noisy labels?

Comment: In both cases, the model output might have a high variance. However, the reasons differ and model capacity is typically adjusted in such a way that the model does not learn the noise in the labels (avoiding overfitting). In the case of noisy input data the model would deal with known unknowns (i.e. label uncertainty). In the case of "out of training distribution queries", the model has to deal with unknown unknowns and there is especially nothing to prevent the high variance of the learned pattern then (except of maybe injecting prior knowledge via some Bayesian approach)

Comment: Thank you very much, this cleared things up for me! @Ggjj11